# How can I update my Android SQLite database from a thread without access to the Context?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

I am working on an Android app. One of the first things the app does upon starting is to launch a listening thread. This listening thread opens a UDP socket to another application on the tablet, and listens for that other application to send data. When my listening thread receives data, I want to store the data into the SQLite database, but I cannot figure out how to do that without access to my app's Context.

I have a database helper app:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, "myAppDatabase.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ...");
    }

    @Override
    public void OnUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE ...");
    }

    // my database CRUD queries
}
```

This DatabaseHelper class is the only place where I perform any CRUD operations on the database.

I start my thread from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ListenerClass myListenerClass = new ListenerClass();
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(myListenerClass);
        listenerThread.setName("My Listener Thread");
        listenerThread.start();
    }
}
```

And I have my listener class:

```
public class ListenerClass implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean run = true;
    private DataProcessingClass myDataProcessingClass;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        // Open UDP socket
        // Listen for data
        // Process the data
        myDatagramSocket.receive(myDatagramPacket);
        byte[] data = myDatagramPacket.getData();
        myDataProcessingClass = new DataProcessingClass();
        myDataProcessingClass.processData(data);
    }

    public void setRun(boolean run){
        this.run = run;
    }
}
```

When my listener thread receives data, it calls another class to process that data, and store it into the database. It works up until I try to store it into the database, because I do not have access to the app's Context.

Is there any way to write to the SQLite database without access to the app's Context? If not, how can I go about getting hold of the Context for this database write?

Comment: One solution is to add a constructor which accepts the context to use. You will need to do this to all classes that need the context, including those that simply pass the context on to another class.

Comment: I thought of that, but it didn't seem very clean. Surely there is a way to do this more cleanly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution which I typically use is to add a constructor which takes a `Context`. In this particular case, you will need to add such a constructor to both `ListenerClass` and to `DataProcessingClass`. The `ListenerClass` constructor will pass the given `Context` to the `DataProcessingClass` constructor.

Alternatively, you can add a `DataProcessingClass(Context)` constructor as before but have a `ListenerClass(DataProcessingClass)` constructor instead. This allows someone else to initialize the `DataProcessingClass` object first so that `ListenerClass` doesn't have to worry about how it is initialized. Also, this allows you to go a step further and use dependency injection for initializing your objects. (Dependency injection is probably a more advanced topic than necessary for this question. I just want to mention it so you can research further if you are interested.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think you will be able to do this without an access to the `Context`.

The only advice I can give you in this direction is to introduce the `Context` as a dependency of the thread.

I would also like to point out a few other things, related to the architecture. Your approach would be totally valid for inter - app communication in the general case, but I think it's a bit suboptimal when it comes to Android.

There are a few ways in which you can leverage out - of - the - box components to do the heavy lifting for you. I would point you to the use of `ContentProviders` - they are ideal for sharing data between apps and will eliminate the need of a UDP connection, dealing with threads and will greatly simplify your app architecture.

Another alternative is to make use of the `Intent` mechanism - you can have App A send intents with binary data to App B. App B can handle those in Broadcast Receivers, which will give you access to a `Context` and the ability to invoke other components of your app, capable of persisting the resulting data.

Comment: +1 For mentioning `ContentProviders`. This might actually be a better solution for the OP than using UDP.

Comment: The only thing is, I have to communicate with the other app via UDP. The other app is a Windows C# app that was ported to Android via Xamarin. It is in-house, and I have to use it. I will try to "introduce the Context as a dependency of the thread" like you suggested. Any suggestions on where to look for examples of this? On a side note, It's pretty crazy that a background process cannot access the background DB without some kind of hook into the main app. Kinda defeats the purpose of MVC separation.

Comment: Introducing the `Context` as a dependency is just basically what @Code-Apprentice pointed out in his answer. As far as the necessity of having a `Context` when you modify the DB, I guess it's a result of Android's security model. The thing is that using `Thread`s directly is considered pretty low level in Android, since the platform provides other utilities to help with multi - threading. You could try and migrate your logic from the thread into an `IntentService`. It will basically do what you need and provide you with a `Context` that you can use for DB updates.

Comment: @Brian "Kinda defeats the purpose of MVC separation." I disagree. Having access to system resources isolated to a single class supports MVC separation.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and provide a static method to get the app context:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static Context sContext;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return sContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sContext = this;
    }
}
```

When an app is launched, the system constructs the`Application` instance and calls its `onCreate()` before creating any activities, services, or receivers (see the comments in the docs for `Application.onCreate()`).  Activity code can thus rely on `MyApplication.getContext()` to always return a valid context.

If you use this approach, remember to also update the application name in your manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="com.example.MyApplication" >
```